# Universal function for displaying elements of any container

Tags: c++, containers

How do I render items to the screen for any container?

I know that you can overload with functions, but you get a lot of functions for different types of containers.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution that will work for *any* container. Mostly because stacks and queues don't have iterators. Then there's the notion that every possible type stored in a container can be "rendered." That assumes some universal method like `operator<<()` or the appropriate `fmt` overloads, but that's **far** from a guarantee. The best you can do is look at what you have and come up with something that suits your particular needs.

Comment: The example at [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) displays all items in a container using `std::for_each(nums.cbegin(), nums.cend(), print);`

Comment: As mentioned there is no universal print function in C++ like for example in javascript. In C++ you need to overload `operator<<` for everything you want to print (or write an appropriate method if you don't want the overload).

Answer (score 1):

> you get a lot of functions for different types of containers

Not if you use templates.

Only matches things that you can iterate:

```
template <std::ranges::range R>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const R & range) {
    for (auto & elem : range) {
        os << elem;
    }
    return os;
}
```

Matches std::pair (for map et.al.), std::tuple and other heterogenous containers:

```
template <typename T>
concept is_tuple = requires { typename std::tuple_size<T>::type; };

template <is_tuple T, std::size_t... Is>
std::ostream& print_tuple(std::ostream& os, const T & tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return os << ... << get<Is>(tuple);
}

template <is_tuple T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T & tuple) {
    return print_tuple(os, tuple, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<T>>{});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a tricky problem, we can enumerate all container types and add printing functions to them. For your customer container, you need to add the macros to add `operator<<`.

The code here is inspired and mostly copied from the [google glog's](https://github.com/google/glog/blob/master/src/glog/stl_logging.h.in) utils code, it works for nested containers.

With some additions :

- overload for forward_list
- overload for std::array

For user-defined types as container elements, we need to define `operator<<` for them too.

```cpp
struct CustomType {
  CustomType(std::string name, int age) : name_(std::move(name)), age_(age) {}

  std::string name_;
  int age_;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const CustomType& ct) {
  out << "name:" << ct.name_ << ","
      << "age:" << ct.age_;
  return out;
}
```

```cpp
// Mostly copied from https://github.com/google/glog/blob/master/src/glog/stl_logging.h.in
#include <deque>
#include <forward_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <ostream>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <class First, class Second>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::pair<First, Second>& p);

template <class Iter>
std::ostream& PrintSequence(std::ostream& out, Iter begin, Iter end);

#define OUTPUT_TWO_ARG_CONTAINER(Sequence)                       \
  template <class T1, class T2>                                  \
  inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,             \
                                  const Sequence<T1, T2>& seq) { \
    return PrintSequence(out, seq.begin(), seq.end());           \
  }

OUTPUT_TWO_ARG_CONTAINER(std::vector)
OUTPUT_TWO_ARG_CONTAINER(std::deque)
OUTPUT_TWO_ARG_CONTAINER(std::list)
OUTPUT_TWO_ARG_CONTAINER(std::forward_list)

#define OUTPUT_THREE_ARG_CONTAINER(Sequence)                         \
  template <class T1, class T2, class T3>                            \
  inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,                 \
                                  const Sequence<T1, T2, T3>& seq) { \
    return PrintSequence(out, seq.begin(), seq.end());               \
  }

OUTPUT_THREE_ARG_CONTAINER(std::set)
OUTPUT_THREE_ARG_CONTAINER(std::multiset)

#define OUTPUT_FOUR_ARG_CONTAINER(Sequence)                              \
  template <class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4>                      \
  inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,                     \
                                  const Sequence<T1, T2, T3, T4>& seq) { \
    return PrintSequence(out, seq.begin(), seq.end());                   \
  }

OUTPUT_FOUR_ARG_CONTAINER(std::map)
OUTPUT_FOUR_ARG_CONTAINER(std::multimap)
OUTPUT_FOUR_ARG_CONTAINER(std::unordered_set)
OUTPUT_FOUR_ARG_CONTAINER(std::unordered_multiset)

#define OUTPUT_FIVE_ARG_CONTAINER(Sequence)                                  \
  template <class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4, class T5>                \
  inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,                         \
                                  const Sequence<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>& seq) { \
    return PrintSequence(out, seq.begin(), seq.end());                       \
  }

OUTPUT_FIVE_ARG_CONTAINER(std::unordered_map)
OUTPUT_FIVE_ARG_CONTAINER(std::unordered_multimap)
template <class First, class Second>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,
                                const std::pair<First, Second>& p) {
  out << '(' << p.first << ", " << p.second << ')';
  return out;
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,
                                const std::array<T, N>& seq) {
  return PrintSequence(out, seq.begin(), seq.end());
}

template <class Iter>
inline std::ostream& PrintSequence(std::ostream& out, Iter begin, Iter end) {
  out << '[';
  for (int i = 0; begin != end; ++i, ++begin) {
    if (i > 0) out << ' ';
    out << *begin;
  }
  if (begin != end) {
    out << " ...";
  }
  out << ']';
  return out;
}

int main() {
  std::vector vec{1, 2, 3};
  std::list lst{1, 2, 3};
  std::forward_list fwd_lst{1, 2, 3};
  std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map{{"foo", 1}, {"bar", 2}};
  std::array<int, 3> arr{1, 2, 3};

  std::cout << "print vector:" << vec << '\n';
  std::cout << "print forward list:" << fwd_lst << '\n';
  std::cout << "print list:" << vec << '\n';
  std::cout << "print array:" << arr << '\n';
  std::cout << "print unordered_map:" << map << '\n';

  std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec2d{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
  std::list<std::unordered_map<std::string, int>> list_of_map{
      {{"foo", 1}, {"bar", 2}}, {{"foo2", 1}, {"bar2", 2}}};
  std::cout << "2d vector:" << vec2d << '\n';
  std::cout << "list of unordered_map:" << list_of_map << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
print vector:[1 2 3]
print forward list:[1 2 3]
print list:[1 2 3]
print array:[1 2 3]
print unordered_map:[(bar, 2) (foo, 1)]
2d vector:[[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]
list of unordered_map:[[(bar, 2) (foo, 1)] [(bar2, 2) (foo2, 1)]]
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6P618qnaP)

There are also other methods like using a member detector, then we avoid the previous ugly macros.

Updated:

The great `fmt` library already support it:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

int main() {
  auto v = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3};
  auto m = std::map<int, int>{{1, 2}};
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec2d{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
  fmt::print("{}", m);
  fmt::print("{}", v);
  fmt::print("{}", vec2d);
}
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v7qsfYxEa)